# Windows Server Backup - Mounted Directories

Tags: mount, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011, windows-server-backup

If I want to back up only the C: for use in a bare metal recovery, does Windows Server Backup also back up the contents of directories used as a mount point? I have a few directories that are used as mount points for other disks, and we already have a different backup method for those so we do not want WSB to back up these folders.

I tried setting exclusions, but the C: does not show up in the list of drives I can set exclusions for.